# change chunk block shape in netCDF file

Tags: python, matlab, netcdf, netcdf4

I have several ~100 GB NetCDF files.
Within each NetCDF file, there is a variable `a`, from which I have to extract several data series
The dimension is `(1440,721,6,8760)`.
I need to extract ~20k slices of dimension `(1,1,1,8760)` from each NetCDF file.
Since it is extremely slow to extract one slice (several minutes), I read about how to optimize the process.
Most likely, the chunks are not set optimally.
Therefore, my goal is to change the chunk size to `(1,1,1,8760)` for a more efficient I/O.

However, I struggle to understand how I can best re-chunk this NetCDF variable.
First of all, by running `ncdump -k file.nc`, I found that the type is `64-bit offset`.
Based on my research, I think this is NetCDF3 which does not support defining chunk sizes.
Therefore, I copied it to NetCDF4 format using `nccopy -k 3 source.nc dest.nc`.
`ncdump -k file.nc` now returns `netCDF-4`.
However, now I'm stuck. I do not know how to proceed.

If anybody has a proper solution in python, matlab, or using nccopy, please share it.
What I'm trying now is the following:

```
nccopy -k 3 -w -c latitude/1,longitude/1,level/1,time/8760 source.nc dest.nc
```

Is this the correct approach in theory?
Unfortunately, after 24 hours, it still did not finish on a potent server with more then enough RAM (250GB) and many CPUs (80).

Comment: did you end up getting this working?

Comment: Are your files compressed ? If so, reading must e.g. `gunzip` (slow) and writing `gzip` (very slow). Try `nccopy -d 0 -4 in.nc out.nc`, compare sizes. Also, extracting one slice at a time is seldom a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Your command appears to be correct. Re-chunking takes time.

```
ncks -4 --cnk_dmn latitude,1 --cnk_dmn longitude,1 --cnk_dmn level,1 --cnk_dmn time,8760 in.nc out.nc
```

to see if that is any faster.